# Why we can’t use sealed classes as generic constraints?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

Can you guess what is the reason to not allow sealed classes for type-constraints in generics? I only have one explanation is to give opportunity to use naked constraints.

Comment: `List<System.Windows.Controls.Button> x = ...` uses the non-sealed `Button` class in a generic constraint, but I'm not sure this what you meant to ask. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question title. It should be "Why we can’t use sealed classes as generic constraints?"

Comment: Also if you can put some code example with the question - it'd really be helpful.

Comment: I have added some code in my answer. it might help.

Comment: @Juliet: In your example `Button` is a *type argument*, not a constraint.

Comment: @G2: I updated the title as well.

Comment: I'd like to know as well - a good use would be for System.Nullable.  I'd like a generic for all items that may use ? operator as in int? double? ...  I'm not finding a way to make a generic that handles all nullable strucs to be able to handle the "HasValue"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If the class is sealed it cannot be inherited. If it cannot be inherited it'd be the only type valid for the generic type argument [assuming if allowed to be a type argument]. If it is the only generic type argument then there's no point in making it generic! You can simply code against the type in non-generic class.

Here's some code for this.

```
public class A
{
    public A() { }
}

public sealed class B : A
{
    public B() { }
}

public class C<T>
        where T : B
{
    public C() { }
}
```

> This will give compiler error: **'B'
>   is not a valid constraint. A type used
>   as a constraint must be an interface,
>   a non-sealed class or a type
>   parameter.**

In addition to this, You can also not have a static class as generic type-constraint. The reason is simple. **Static classes** are marked as **abstract** and **sealed** in compiled **IL** which can be neither instantiated nor inherited.

Here's the code for this.

```
public class D<T>
        where T : X
{
    public D() { }
}

public static class X
{
}
```

> This will give compiler error:**'X':
>   static classes cannot be used as
>   constraints.**

Comment: Generics is a way to use algorithms universally and to get better performance. So I slightly disagree with your point about inheritance.

Comment: But there's absolutely now way that you could instantiate a C object of any type other than C<B>.  Because B is sealed it can have no subclasses, thus there is no other type that will match "where T : B".  Therefore, the type T will always be B; otherwise, the constraint fails.

If your generic code is constrained so that it applies to exactly one type, is it still generic? :)

Comment: Incidentally, if a class has two generic type parameters, one of which inherits from the other, it's perfectly acceptable for both parameters to be the same sealed class.  Even though the fact that the second parameter is a sealed class would imply that the first parameter must be the same sealed class, there's no compiler complaint.  I think the basic reason for the complaint was to encourage people not to use generic type parameters which could only ever be one type.

Comment: What about the case where you're using multiple constraints? ie: `where T : SomeSealedClass, SomeNonSealedClass` - for example, if both constraints have similar methods / members but don't actually inherit the same class or use a common interface, what is your option then?

Comment: The argument above is invalid. A generic type of System.ValueTuple permits multiple 'types' of input, is a perfectly legitimate need, but is disallowed by the compiler.

Comment: My use-case is purely based on lazyness. My constraint class has a long name and several parameters e.g.: `class ClassWithConstraint<T> where T: ClassWithLongNameAndSeveralGenericArguments<A,B,C>`. The only reason for doing this here is that code is much more concise e.g.: `private T GetStuff(T other, T whatever)`. When do we get C++ style `#define` in C#?

Answer (score 5):

Are you talking about something like this:

```
class NonSealedClass
{
}

class Test<T> where T : NonSealedClass
{
}
```

Because it's perfectly legal.

Comment: He mentioned using a non-sealed class as a generic constraint, I guess he probably meant a sealed class...

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I don't quite see the point of it.

As [this.__curious_geek points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945085/why-cant-we-use-sealed-classes-as-generic-constraints/1945101#1945101), a sealed class cannot be inherited and so using one as a constraint might **seem** nonsensical.

But there's no guarantee that a sealed class will never be "unsealed" -- i.e., that the developer might rearrange its implementation to make it more amenable to inheritance and then remove the `sealed` modifier from the class definition (or just flat-out remove the `sealed` keyword for no reason at all).

I know a lot of developers actually encourage this practice: not removing the `sealed` keyword per se, but rather *adding* the `sealed` keyword liberally and only supporting inheritance when the decision to do so is made explicitly (and at this point, yes, removing the `sealed` keyword).

So I'm not sure why you couldn't use the type of a sealed class as a generic constraint. After all, you could always use the type of a class that just happens to not have any derived classes, even though it's not sealed. The two scenarios don't seem all that different to me.

I'm probably missing something, though. I'm sure [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/) could give a pretty killer explanation.

Comment: This seems like a stretch... to the extent it is an issue why couldn't you just take advantage of polymorphism on your non-generic method?

Comment: Usually, when it comes to compile-time checking, every bit of compiled code is considered in its current state. Yes, a sealed class might be unsealed in the future, so maybe the compiler shouldn't output an error. But then, maybe that other method will get an overload with an additional argument in the future, and maybe that unknown class will be added in the future - does that mean that all of those compiler errors should be suppressed, just because the respective lines of code will be meaningful in the future?

Answer (score 1):

A naked constraint is where one generic type inherits from another e.g.

```
where X:Y
```

One generic parameter derives from another generic parameter

```
class Foo<T>
{
    Foo<S> SubsetFoo<S>() where S : T {  }
}
```

So the class cannot be sealed.

You can also inherit from generics in the normal way so you would not want them sealed.

Comment: but I want S to be of type T. Not to inherit

Comment: you could use class or a type of interface